# Preposition with abschreiben

Tags: preposition

Which preposition goes with the verb abschreiben?

For example if I want to say

> During the exam he copied the answer from his colleague

Do I say

> Während der Prüfung hat er die Antwort von seinem Kollegen abgeschrieben

or

> Während der Prüfung hat er die Antwort bei seinem Kollegen abgeschrieben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both versions are correct, good style and they mean the same.

- **von** jemandem abschreiben

  - [Jetzt wirft ihr der Sachbuchautor Peter Leuschner vor, **von** ihm abgeschrieben zu haben.](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/plagiatsvorwurf-gegen-tannoed-andrea-m-schenkel-es-geht-nur-ums-geld-1435332.html)
  - [Ein Münchner Journalist warf der Bestsellerautorin vor, **von** ihm abgeschrieben zu haben und zog vor Gericht.](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/tannoed-plagiatsprozess-gericht-sieht-keine-urheberrechtsverletzung-1514232.html)
  - [Also, vermutlich ist Herrn Hellermann das Heft gestohlen und der Verfasser des ›Kämpfer‹ hat **von** ihm abgeschrieben.](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/berndt/gestgeda/chap007.html)
  - [Das inkriminierte Wort stamme nämlich nicht von Baerbock selbst, sondern sei selbstverständlich bloß **von** ihr abgeschrieben worden.](https://www.welt.de/satire/article232738983/Entwarnung-Annalena-Baerbock-hat-N-Wort-bloss-abgeschrieben.html)
  - [Sogar Scott Fitzgerald hat **von** ihr abgeschrieben](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/f-a-z-fruehjahrsbuecher-2009/belletristik/willa-cather-die-frau-die-sich-verlor-die-frau-aus-der-praerie-1928147.html)
- **bei** jemandem abschreiben

  - [Valentino Rossi: Ja, ich habe **bei** Vinales abgeschrieben](https://de.motorsport.com/motogp/news/valentino-rossi-ja-ich-habe-bei-vinales-abgeschrieben-739101/739101/)
  - [Marc Buhl glaubt, dass Christian Kracht **bei** ihm abgeschrieben hat](https://www.morgenpost.de/printarchiv/kultur/article106042407/Marc-Buhl-glaubt-dass-Christian-Kracht-bei-ihm-abgeschrieben-hat.html)
  - [Hans Rott wurde keine 26 Jahre alt, und als 1989 seine E-Dur-Symphonie ausgegraben wurde, tuschelte man, Mahler habe **bei** ihm abgeschrieben.](https://rso.orf.at/programm/4137)
  - [Es hieß, die Autorin Özdamar habe dem Autor Zaimoglu vorgeworfen, er habe **bei** ihr abgeschrieben.](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/literatur/zaimoglu-roman-oezdamar-dementiert-plagiatsvorwurf-a-420334.html)
  - [Die Hamburger Rechtsanwältin Tanja Eisenblätter wirft Saß vor, **bei** ihr abgeschrieben zu haben.](https://www.bz-berlin.de/artikel-archiv/stoiber-tochter-verliert-doktor-titel)
- Both versions in the same Text:

  - [Der Autor Karsten Weitzenegger, **von** dem Armin Laschet abgeschrieben hatte, reagierte gelassen auf das Plagiat. Er habe sich nicht vorstellen können, dass Laschet bei seiner heutigen Einstellung **bei** ihm abgeschrieben habe, ...](https://www.merkur.de/politik/armin-laschet-plagiat-affaere-cdu-kanzlerkandidat-buch-quelle-fehler-bundestagswahl-2021-90892591.html)

Answer (score 4):

Both are in use and fine. For example, Linguee and DWDS Kernkorpus have examples of both.

From Linguee:

> Aber sie wird halt hingenommen, weil man bei ihr die Hausaufgaben abschreiben kann, weil sie die Sportbeutel zur Turnhalle trägt etc.

Examples from DWDS Kernkorpus:

> hier hat einer vom anderen abgeschrieben.

> Ich - selbst gern und oft unterwegs - hab' einiges bei ihm abgeschrieben.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.